# Card Scanning Feature iOS

Tags: ios, touch, scanning

I came across this very cool feature of iOS from this [video](http://vimeo.com/42738280) Any idea how is it possible? Hope they can exploit this wonderful feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete guess, but some parts of the card are presumably conductive (you can get [conductive ink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_ink), after all) and hence generate what looks like normal multi-touch activity when pressed against the screen.

Mystery solved. :-)

Comment: Sounds interesting - Thank you. lets wait for the answers to roll in. Hope its useful for someone like me out there

Comment: U WIN :) http://venturebeat.com/2012/08/21/nukotoys-launches-its-intelligent-hybrid-apps-that-combine-toys-and-games/